# How do you configure a socket in the kernel to be nonblocking or a timeout on an accept() call?

Tags: sockets, linux-kernel, blocking, nonblocking

In a Linux kernel module, I want calls to a listening socket's accept handler to not sit and wait in a kernel thread.  So I need to either pass `O_NONBLOCK` to the accept handler.  But I want to use a timeout on the connected socket, not a nonblocking socket.

I know of two mechanisms to configure a socket in the kernel to be nonblocking.  Pass O_NONBLOCK to the accept or connect handlers in `sock->op` (`struct socket * sock`).  I do not know how to reset the O_NONBLOCK flag after that.  How do you change the O_NONBLOCK flag on a socket otherwise?

Is there an alternative method, such as a timeout on accept?  This would allow the connected socket on the listening port to be blocking.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the term "socket" is used to refer to several different things. The one in user space (that is referred to through an open file description with a small integer value) has a state you can set with `fcntl`. The one in kernel space (a pointer to the actual connection endpoint) doesn't. Passing `O_NONBLOCK` to the accept or connect handlers only makes that particular accept or connect operation non-blocking.

Comment: just a portability note: "Linux accept does _not_ inherit socket flags like O_NONBLOCK. This behaviour differs from other BSD socket implementations."